# I can't transform numeric numbers into time

Tags: r

Here's the structure of the data

[image]

What I want to do is to change the form of `Time` into `POSIXct`.

Here's what I have tried.

```
a <- as.POSIXct(power_consumption$Time, "%H:%M:%S")
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  字符串的格式不够标准明确(The format of the string is not standard enough)

a <- as.POSIXlt(power_consumption$Time, "%H:%M:%S")
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  字符串的格式不够标准明确(The format of the string is not standard enough) 

a <- strptime(power_consumption$Time, "%H:%M:%S")
head(a)
[1] NA                        "2017-07-07 17:24:00 CST" "2017-07-07 17:25:00 CST" "2017-07-07 17:26:00 CST" "2017-07-07 17:27:00 CST"
[6] "2017-07-07 17:28:00 CST"
```

I don't think the result is right, for the struction of `Time` has **time only**.

What should I do to transform `Time` into `%H:%M:%S`? Thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (image of the data is not enough).

Comment: Maybe try the [`anytime` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=anytime)?

Comment: I can't think of any reason to use time only, and POSIXct includes both date and time `dt <- as.POSIXct(paste(power_consumption$Date,power_consumption$Time), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: @HubertL Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for the remind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition POSIX time formats must have a date associated with them. If the date doesn't matter, you can proceed as is, and specify an `origin` date if you care which will set everything to an arbitrary date you provide.

You can follow @HubertL's advice and construct the full POSIX object, which seems like the most logical option.

Alternatively you can use `chron::times()` to simply store everything in an HH:MM:SS object. There's also `hms::as.hms()`

Unless you have a specific reason why you need to keep date and time separate, just construct the full POSIX date/time object.

Also, I should add that by default, POSIXct/lt will assign a date (in this case today's) if you don't provide one, hence all of yours saying 2017-07-07.

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan You need to reload the data frame from the source and set each column to the correct data type. Everything in`power_consumption` should be a double except the date and time. You will be unable to do any serious processing, because all the data is represented as factors.